# systemd oneshot moves to inactive (dead) after a few weeks

Tags: systemd

I have three systemd configs enabled:

1. The service I actually want to run (a dotnet process):

```
# systemd.conf
[Unit]
Description=MyService
After=network.target
StartLimitIntervalSec=0

[Service]
# Foreground process (do not use --daemon in ExecStart or config.rb)
Type=simple

User=deployer

# The path to the application root
WorkingDirectory=/srv/myapp/current/bin

ExecStart=/bin/bash -c "dotnet MyService.dll"

Restart=always
RestartSec=5s

Environment="ThreadPool_ForceMinWorkerThreads=200"
Environment="COMPlus_ThreadPool_ForceMinWorkerThreads=200"
Environment="COMPlus_ThreadPool_ForceMaxWorkerThreads=10000"

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

2. A restarter and restarter-path to monitor for a file being touched (which will trigger the above service to restart):

```
# systemd-restarter.conf
[Unit]
Description=MyService restart
After=network.target

[Service]
Type=oneshot

ExecStart=/bin/bash -c "pkill -f 'dotnet MyService.dll'"

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

```
# systemd-restarter-path.conf
[Path]
PathModified=/srv/myapp/shared/restart.txt

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

After a few weeks suddenly the systemd-restarter-path.conf and systemd-restarter.conf enter a dead (inactive) status, and I have no idea why.

We use capistrano for deploys, so it touches a restart.txt file, and systemd restarts the process.

Example systemctl commands:

```
# systemctl status restart-service.service
● restart-service.service - restart
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/restart-service.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: inactive (dead) since Sat 2020-10-10 00:41:11 UTC; 20h ago
 Main PID: 3037 (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
```

```
# systemctl status restart.path
● restart.path
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/restart.path; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: inactive (dead) since Sat 2020-10-10 00:43:30 UTC; 20h ago
```

If I run systemctl restart on restart.path and restart-service.service it starts working again. Or if I just reboot the server.

Any ideas why it stops watching the restart.txt file?